# Warning: file_put_contents: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, html, ajax, base64

```
    function uploadImgBase64 ($base64, $name){
        // decodificamos el base64
        $datosBase64 = base64_decode(preg_replace('#^data:image/\w+;base64,#i', '', $base64));
        // definimos la ruta donde se guardara en el server
        $path= $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/firmas/'.$name;
        // guardamos la imagen en el server
   ---> if(!file_put_contents($path, $datosBase64)){
            // retorno si falla
            return false;
        }
        else{
            // retorno si todo fue bien
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Estoy intentando enviar un archivo canvas a un directorio especifico, y me arroja un error en la línea que señale con una flecha:

> Warning: file_put_contents(c:/xampp/htdocs/img/ordenes/firmas/):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\servicios\firmas.php on line 152

necesito que se guarde en la carpeta c:\xampp\htdocs\img\firmas

Es mi primer pregunta, espero me puedan ayudar

Comment: `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` que ruta viene aca?

Comment: si prestaras atencion verias que `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` apunta a `c:/xampp/htdocs/img/ordenes/firmas/` y no a `c:\xampp\htdocs\img\firmas`